# UnicodeDecodeError when using device detector library

Tags: python

i am trying to use the dvice detactor parser in this way

```
from device_detector import DeviceDetector

ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; 4Good Light A103 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36'
device = DeviceDetector(ua).parse()
```

im getting the  the follwing error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mozer/PycharmProjects/test/new.py", line 83, in <module>
    device = DeviceDetector(ua).parse()
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\device_detector.py", line 230, in parse
    self.parse_client()
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\device_detector.py", line 248, in parse_client
    parser = Parser(self.user_agent, self.ua_hash, self.ua_spaceless).parse()
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\parser\parser.py", line 86, in parse
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\parser\client\base.py", line 92, in _parse
    app_details = self.appdetails_data
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\yaml_loader.py", line 125, in appdetails_data
    all_app_details.extend(self.yaml_to_list('{}'.format(fixture)))
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\yaml_loader.py", line 63, in yaml_to_list
    regexes = self.load_from_yaml(yfile)
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\device_detector\yaml_loader.py", line 35, in load_from_yaml
    return yaml.load(yf, SafeLoader)
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "C:\Users\mozer\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\constructor.py", line 41, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "ext\_yaml.pyx", line 707, in _yaml.CParser.get_single_node
  File "ext\_yaml.pyx", line 725, in _yaml.CParser._compose_document
  File "ext\_yaml.pyx", line 774, in _yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "ext\_yaml.pyx", line 853, in _yaml.CParser._compose_sequence_node
  File "ext\_yaml.pyx", line 903, in _yaml.CParser._parse_next_event
  File "ext\_yaml.pyx", line 912, in _yaml.input_handler
  File "C:\Users\mozer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 10444: character maps to <undefined>
```

i saw this issue mainly in attempts to read a file.
someone have any idea?

thanks

Comment: Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Is that the entire error message/traceback?

Comment: its in python 3 .

Comment: I update the error message/traceback

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `encoding="utf-8"` to the line that opens the regexs
i.e. change it to read:

`with open('{}/{}'.format(ROOT, yfile), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as yf:`

For me this is line 34 of "yaml_loader.py" in the device_detector folder